# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException when using getFont

Tags: java, android, snackbar

I developed an android application that is based on Firebase.

One of the buttons In the application is used to delete the account.

Once the account is deleted, I return the user to the main activity by using this:

```
AuthUI.getInstance()
        .signOut( context )
        .addOnCompleteListener( task -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent( context, MainActivity.class );
            intent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
            context.startActivity( intent );
        } );
```

Then, when the main activity is created, there are few methods in it.
One of the methods called `activateGPS` is used when users first open the app to tell them that they should turn on the GPS.

```
private void activateGPS() {
    new GpsUtils( this ).turnGPSOn( isGPSEnable -> isGPS = isGPSEnable );

    if (!isGPS) {
        PopUps popUps = new PopUps();
        popUps.popSnack( getApplicationContext(), getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById( android.R.id.content ), getString( R.string.Location_Service ) );
    }
}
```

What causes this problem?

When I run it on the emulator everything seems to work fine.

Thank you
If the GPS turned off, a snackbar is shown.

Problem is, that I see in my logs is that when users deleted their accounts, the following error happened:

```
Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException
Font resource ID #0x7f090000 could not be retrieved.

androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat.loadFont (ResourcesCompat.java:4)
androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat.getFont (ResourcesCompat.java:19)
com.xx.yy.PopUps.popSnack (PopUps.java:4)
com.xx.yy.MainActivity.activateGPS (MainActivity.java:8)
```

`PopUps.popSnack` is built as follows and I use it from an interface:

```
public void popSnack(Context context, View view, String message) {
    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make( view.findViewById( android.R.id.content ), message, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT );
    View sbView = snackbar.getView();
    sbView.setBackgroundColor( context.getResources().getColor( R.color.colorPrimaryDark ) );
    sbView.setElevation( 0f );

    TextView tv = (snackbar.getView()).findViewById( com.google.android.material.R.id.snackbar_text );
    Typeface font = ResourcesCompat.getFont( context, R.font.assistant );
    tv.setTypeface( font );
    tv.setTextSize( 12 );

    if (view.findViewById( R.id.et_Message ) != null) {
        snackbar.setAnchorView( R.id.et_Message );
    } else if (view.findViewById( R.id.bottom_navigation ) != null) {
        snackbar.setAnchorView( R.id.bottom_navigation );
    }
    snackbar.setDuration( 5000 );
    snackbar.show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the error you have mentioned, I think the resource you are trying to access isn't available. **Please make sure that the file is in the font folder.**

```
   ResourcesCompat.getFont(context,R.font.assistant);
```

The above code should work fine.

Comment: But how will it kniw which font? I have more than one...

Comment: getResources().getFont(R.font.assistant);

Comment: It is only available to API > 26. What to do for lower ones? My min SDK is 21